# What is the total energy of a transform limited pulse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics, photoelectric-effect

Something like a holy grail of quantum physics would be, if we could explain *why* $E=hf$. Einstein, originally meant a finite number of energy quanta, instead of the usual continuous Maxwell equations. But what if we can, now much later in time and with better experimental setups, further analyze those energy quanta and they turn out to be not elementary after all? It seems to me like quanta and transform-limited laser pulses have a lot in common. We can view photons as atom sized transform-limited wave-packets, it seems. Now, for such pulses, it is true, that for shorter pulses, you need higher average frequencies of the wave packet. The reason for that, is that you need as broad a frequency bandwidth as possible. But if you have a center frequency of only, say, $10$ MHz, you can't have a Gaussian distribution around it, that is much broader than $10$ MHz, because then you would reach zero and negative frequencies. If the same is true for photons, then we have a mechanism by which more energy requires higher frequency, hence Energy proportional to (average) frequency. If we try to re-examine the photoelectric effect in that light, we arrive at the following: While higher amplitude of the overall field only means more photons. Higher frequency means we have photons of higher energy, because the internal amplitude of such transform-limited wave packets is higher. An electron hit by it gets excited to the next higher (dynamic) state. For lower energy wave packets, nothing happens or the electron relaxes way before the next energy quantum arrives...

Footnotes:

1. The most extreme theoretical example would be an infinitely short, infinitely high amplitude delta pulse.
2. Another picture that I had earlier, which might turn out to be a different perspective on the same thing, is the following: With higher frequency, more oscillations can fit into the Gaussian envelope and therefore more energy...

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you just asking whether the picture you have in mind about photons is correct?

Comment: @flippiefanus I'm having difficulty figuring out for sure whether the energy of a transform limited pulse scales indeed exactly linearly with the center frequency. If someone could help me out by providing an exact formular for the title question, that would be great, for example....

Comment: @flippiefanus I mean energy in terms of Maxwell's equation, not referring back to photons. Please excuse, if I don't respond for a while, I'm exhausted by math...